# Moving Magento Advanced Search Link From Footer To Beneath Search Bar

Tags: magento, advanced-search

I'm trying to move magentos advanced search link from the footer links right beneath the search bar.

I know that the origins of the link are in layout/catalogsearch.xml under 
reference name="footer_links" and appear in the footer because of `getChildHtml('footer_links')` in footer.phtml

And i know that the search bar originates from template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml and appears though catalogsearch.xml under reference name="top.menu"

Any ideas on how to proceed here?

Comment: Title is very misleading

Answer (score 3):

thank you for the quick answer!
But it is not exactly what I was looking for as it would display the entire footer links block beneath the searchbar.
Nevertheless thank you for showing me the method you used for that!

Anyways, I figured out a solution on my own:

I modified catalogsearch.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.menu"> 
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/> 
    </reference>


<!-- add a new reference to top.search including my new adv.search block -->
    <reference name="top.search"> 
        <block type="page/template_links" name="adv.search" as="adv.search" >

            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalogsearch"> 
                <label>Advanced Search</label>
                <url helper="catalogsearch/getAdvancedSearchUrl" />
                <title>Advanced Search</title>
            </action>       

        </block>
    </reference>  
<!-- the reference to the footer i commented out as its not longer needed; it includes advanced search and popular search terms-->
</default>
```

In form.mini.phtml I added a new div that calls adv.search:

```
</script>

<div class="adv-search"> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('adv.search') ?> </div>

</div>
```

And last, in styles.css, I added some code to controll the looks of that div:

```
.adv-search {width:100px; height:15px; margin-top:24px; margin-left: 120px;}
.adv-search a { color:#fff; font-weight:bold; }
```

any additional advice is more than welcome

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you must:

1) Update your app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/layout/local.xml file

2) Call the new blocks in app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/template/page/html/header.phtml - this is needed because header.phtml is not a "core/text_list" block type which automatically renders its nested blocks. So we must explicitly tell Magento to render those child blocks

Your app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/layout/local.xml should contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>

        <reference name="header">

            <!-- Insert cms links. No need to use <action method="insert"> as this block is not used elsewhere in layout -->
            <block type="cms/block" name="top_links_cms" as="top_links_cms" before="top_links_other">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
            </block>

            <!-- Insert former footer links. -->
            <action method="insert">
                <!-- We must keep block name "footer_links" as it is used as a reference for adding links by other modules -->
                <blockName>footer_links</blockName>
                <!-- Name of the block we want to have as sibling (in order to get its position and place our block after it. See next node <after> -->
                <siblingName>topSearch</siblingName>
                <!-- $after param from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::insert() is a boolean type, so its value in the XML node is [empty], 0 or 1 -->
                <after>1</after>
                <alias>top_links_other</alias>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>footer_links</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cms_footer_links</name></action>
        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

This is an updated header.phtml you can get inspiration from for your app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/template/page/html/header.phtml file:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>



            <?php
            /**
             * Add other top links (footer and cms links)
             */
            ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_links_cms') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top_links_other') ?>



            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```